# Node.js/express integration test with jest/supertest suitable for automated tests

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, automated-tests, integration-testing

Given a `nodejs/express` web api application which works with `MySQL`, `MongoDB` and calls some external apis and services, we want to add testing with `jest` and `supertest`.

Now, what are the ways for integration testing, calling apis which includes all code from controller to database? in-memory databases, mocking and dedicated database for testing are options.

One important use case is automated tests under CI/CD tools.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my sample test file for you

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../app');

dotenv.config({ path: '.env.test' });

describe('Test Armature Type', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(20 * 1000);
    let user = null;
    let armatureType = null;

    test('login Super Admin', async () => {
        await request(app)
            .post('/api/v1/auth/login')
            .send({
                email: process.env.SUPER_ADMIN_EMAIL,
                password: process.env.SUPER_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            })
            .then((resLogin) => {
                expect(resLogin.statusCode).toBe(200);
                const bodyLogin = JSON.parse(resLogin.res.text);
                user = bodyLogin.data;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.toString());
            });
    });

    test('create Armature Type', async () => {
        await request(app)
            .post('/api/v1/armature/type/create')
            .send({
                name: 'TEST'
            })
            .set({ Authorization: `Bearer ${user.access_token}` })
            .then((resCreate) => {
                expect(resCreate.statusCode).toBe(200);
                const bodyResCreate = JSON.parse(resCreate.res.text);
                armatureType = bodyResCreate.data;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.toString());
            });
    });

    test('edit Armature Type', async () => {
        await request(app)
            .post('/api/v1/armature/type/edit')
            .send({
                armatureTypeId: armatureType._id,
                name: 'TEST NEW'
            })
            .set({ Authorization: `Bearer ${user.access_token}` })
            .then((resEdit) => {
                expect(resEdit.statusCode).toBe(200);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.toString());
            });
    });

    test('delete Armature Type', async () => {
        await request(app)
            .post('/api/v1/armature/type/delete')
            .send({
                armatureTypeId: armatureType._id
            })
            .set({ Authorization: `Bearer ${user.access_token}` })
            .then((resDelete) => {
                expect(resDelete.statusCode).toBe(200);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.toString());
            });
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    });
});
```